# How do I disable a button if another button is clicked?

Tags: flutter

I'm just starting to get the hang of Flutter, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to disable a button if another button is clicked

Currently I have 20 buttons and each one can be selected lets say

[image]

At the moment I have 20 booleans checking if each button is selected (which already I know it can be done easier but nothing is coming to mind)

How can I select a button, then if another button is clicked an AlertDialog would show up with two options (cancel or continue) ?

If you choose cancel everything stays as it is but if you choose continue the button you clicked is now active and the one you had clicked previously becomes inactive

Here is what happens when you click on a button number 1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe change all the booleans for a list of booleans will be more easy to do something that you need.
Every button will have an index for identify itself, and his index will be the index at the list that you will create.

`final buttonsState = List.generate(20, (index) => false, growable: false);`

This list above will be your state for your buttons. That's it for the state.

About the principal problem...
First you need make your button a component enabling you to reuse this, will be something like this:

```
class ButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Identifier for your button
  final int index;

  /// The whole list of your buttons state
  final List<bool> currentStates;

  const ButtonWidget({required this.index, required this.currentStates});

  @override
  _ButtonWidgetState createState() => _ButtonWidgetState();
}

class _ButtonWidgetState extends State<ButtonWidget> {
  /// If the button was selected will be enabled
  bool get selected => widget.currentStates[widget.index];

  void showDialogConfirm(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return AlertDialog(
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  /// clearing the list
                  widget.currentStates.clear();

                  /// setting the whole list to false
                  widget.currentStates
                      .addAll(widget.currentStates.map((e) => false));

                  /// setting the index of your button to true
                  widget.currentStates[widget.index] = true;

                  /// and pop
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Continue'),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () => showDialogConfirm(context),
      child: Text('Button: ${widget.index} is $selected'),
    );
  }
}
```

And you can use the button like this:

```
class UsingTheButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final buttonsState = List.generate(20, (index) => false, growable: false);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ButtonWidget(index: 1, currentStates: buttonsState),
        ButtonWidget(index: 2, currentStates: buttonsState),
        ButtonWidget(index: 3, currentStates: buttonsState),
        ButtonWidget(index: 4, currentStates: buttonsState),
        ButtonWidget(index: 5, currentStates: buttonsState),
        ButtonWidget(index: 6, currentStates: buttonsState),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

So every time you click in a button you will open the dialog.
When you click continue, you will deselect all the others buttons and select one that you clicked.
ps. In this example I only used flutter, without any lib.